# Unable to upload image with Rails PaperClip Gem with angular 9+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby

I am using rails as a backend and angular as a frontend. I want to save images to rails backend. I decided to use the paperclip gem. Here is the error below.

> ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:49:in `set_product'
> Unpermitted parameters: :id, :created_at, :updated_at,
> :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size,
> :image_updated_at

Here is some model for angular.

```
export class Product {
  public image:File;
  ...//the rest of the variables
}
```

Here is where I set the value of the products image.

```
public fileSelected(event) {
    this.product.image=event.target.files[0];
  }
```

Then I use the httpclient angular functions to send it. That all is working so I wont show it unless requested. Only with an image does this fail.

On the rails side. Here is the paperclip migration

```
class AddAttachmentImageToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :products, :image
  end
end
```

My model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

My controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    render json:  @products.to_json
  end
  # GET /products/1
  def show
    render json: @products.image
  end

  # POST /products
  def create
    @products = Product.new(product_params)

    if @products.save
      render json: @products, status: :created, location: @products
    else
      render json: @products.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  def update
    if @products.update(product_params)
      render json: @products
    else
      render json: @products.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  def destroy
    @products.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @products = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :image)

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails API, then you should use paperclip adapters to save the image. You have to send base64 file from front end.

```
 def update
   @products.name = params[:product][:name]
   @products.description = params[:product][:description]
   image_base = params[:product][:image] ###base64 text of your image came from front-end
   image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(image_base)
   image.original_filename = "image" ###Name of the file, you can take it from parameters / you can assign it statically
   @products.image = image
   if @products.save
      ##Do your stuff
   else
     render json: @products.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
 end
```

In case if you get any exceptions after adding above code in your controller, create a config/initializers/paperclip.rb file and place the following code in that initializer

```
  Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register
  require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
  module Paperclip
   class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
     false
    end
   end
  end
```

Comment: Yeah I think you got me on the right track. I wasn't even sending base64. This is my first time ever needing to work with sending images like this. So now it's sending base64. The rails backend is getting it in the params. But its still sending an improcessable entry.

Comment: Are you using paperclip io adapters, as I posted. Please provide the updated code and the error.

Comment: nvm got it thanks to your direction. I will make  a response tomorrow as it's late for me. For language that will maybe work for people who were as clueless as I was. I just needed to get the binding.pry gem in this project, and there where just a few things off. But yeah your code was what I needed as well as the direction to send base 64

Comment: As you accepted my answer, upvote it if possible